# Accessing UI Components from an INSTANCE of a stage in JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

I am writing a notetaker software in javaFX, using Scene Builder and Netbeans IDE.

I would like the user to be able to open a limitless number of (notetaking) windows (just like in an application like notepad), and then hit a "save all" button, which will then read from the textareas on each of those windows.

My current problem is in accessing those textareas.

There are two FXML files in the project, one of which is a generic template for the notes (however many the user chooses to open).

Help would really be appreciated!

So far, I have been able to launch these limitless notetaking windows with no problem. I have two controller classes, with a getText() method in the one that corresponds to FXMLTemplate (the one used for the notes themselves as opposed to the main screen).

The other class, which contains the code relevant to launching the (limitless) notes, stores each of the new stages created in a global arraylist called "arrayOfStages". I am also concerned about whether the arraylist of stages contains (references to) the instances of those stages themselves, rather copies of the same reference to the static template class). Is this the case? If someone could clarify this for me, that would be great!

I have tried going the getText() route as well as the accessing-the-textarea route, and have so far failed at both (ie. referencing that particular instance of the controller class vs accessing a UI element from the instance of the stage(stored in the array)). I have failed at both, so far:(

Let me know if the code would be helpful and I'll post it here. I would really appreciate any help you guys can provide!

:)

So this is the section responsible for launching a theoretically limitless number of notetaker windows:

```html
public void newNote()
    {//intuntitlednotenumber
        //hold an global array of Stage objects (the note windows themselves), to access those stages
        
        try{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Template.fxml"));    
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        Stage aStage = new Stage();            
        aStage.setScene(scene);
        arrayOfStages.add(aStage);
        aStage.show();    
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        
        }
        
        
        //array of "new notes" ie stages

    }
    
}
```

And this is the section in which I attempt to save these (I need help in referencing the anchorpane located in the stage, assuming that the instances themselves were stored in the array (I hope so...but I'm not really sure). The part I would like help with is here):

```html
for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfStages.size(); i++)
            {
                try{
                AnchorPane frame = arrayOfStages.get(i).getScene().getRoot().get....//<--- I'm not really sure what to do here, or if this technique will really work...ie. get me the INSTANCE of the anchorpane from the INSTANCE of the stage, and in turn the textarea
                Node n = frame.getChildren().get(0);
                TextArea a = (TextArea) n;
                System.out.println(a.getText()); //this print statement is for testing purposes, later on, I will store the extracted text in a textfile
                }     
                catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
```

I wasn't really sure where to go from here. I've tried a ridiculous number of things at this point, and I can't keep one straight from the other anymore:P

Is this approach correct or is it flawed in terms of how instancing works?
How *would* I go about referencing the anchorpane by using the instance of the stage in the array?

Comment: Can you post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please?

Comment: I think all you want is the text in the TextArea when the user is attempting to save the application and it should be available to you :)

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I want...the text from a variable number of textareas....I'm not sure how to access these...I just updated the question with the relevant code.:)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution in case anyone's interested:

```
Node node1 = arrayOfStages.get(i).getScene().getRoot();
AnchorPane ap = (AnchorPane) node1;
Node n =...
```

The rest is the same as the code in the question.